# Installing new smart switch in dual gang - tripping circuit breaker

Tags: smart-switch

I am attempting to replace a motion-sensing light switch with a new smart switch.  It is in a dual gang box and shares the line wire with the lutron 1.5a ceiling fan controller switch.

I am attaching a picture of the wiring as I found it when I opened it up.

The smart switch is pretty straight forward.  Insert neutral (white) wire and tighten screw, insert line (black)wire and tighten screw, insert load (red) wire and tighten screw.  Flip breaker.  Breaker trips.  I can update with a pic if necessary.

When I switch back to the motion sensing light switch, breaker flips on with no problem and the switches work.   The smart switch troubleshooting instructions suggested reversing the load and line wires, which I did and the breaker will turn on, I even get power to the gang as the fan controller will turn on.  But smart the switch doesn't appear to be getting power.  Suggestions?

This is a single pole light/fan, and the smart switch is single pole.  The fan switch is single or 3-way.

I called their support, walked through the entire process again, and they told me to return it, it was a defective switch.  So I returned it and picked up a couple more from a different store, same brand.  All had the same result. I just have a feeling that the problem isn't a defect...[image]

[image]

Comment: 1 - Most important: Manufacturer/model # of the new switch? 2 - Is the new switch replacing the switch on the left or the right? 3 - It looks like (but not 100% clear) you have a green ground connecting to a white neutral on the right - if that's true, it is a problem.

Comment: It's brand new to the market.  Wyze smart switch.  I'm replacing the one on the right.  Sorry, I tried to include the all the correct details but my mind was tired after hours of searching for answers.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the breaker that is tripping? Well really, I'm interested in whether the breaker has a "Test" button.

Comment: It does have a test button. I'm adding pic to the post.  It is the 2nd circuit up from the bottom on the left.  Front bedroom/utility.  (although I've now learned that all of the kitchen lights which are in the center of the house also run on this circuit as well as the exterior lights. what is going on here?!)

Comment: A lot of lights (especially with modern LED lights) can be safely on one circuit. Since lighting rarely trips breakers, and the wiring can snake from one room to the next, there is little reason not to do so. Though preferably would be two circuits with alternating rooms, so that if a circuit trips or (more commonly) is turned off for maintenance, you are not left in the dark.

Comment: @Laura -- does the breaker flash a light at you when you turn it back on?